Inserting into SwiftData
I am trying to write some code which inserts a new item into SwiftData if it doesn’t already exist. I’m getting errors regarding the ModelContext which I can’t work out.
The following code is a stripped-down version which is enough to generate the errors. I’ve removed the logic to test for an existing item until I can get past this problem.
Sorry it’s so long:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class TestData {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var value: String
    init(id: String, value: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct EditTestItem: View {
    @Bindable var testData: TestData
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text($testData.id)
                TextField("Enter Data Here", text: $testData.value)
            }
        }
        .modelContainer(for: TestData.self)
    }
}

struct TestContent: View {
    var testIDValue: String = ""
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query var testData: [TestData]
    var testItem: TestData
        
    init(testID: String) {
        testItem = TestData(id: testID, value: "New value: \(testID)")

        let _ = modelContext.insert(testItem)
                    
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("\(#line) oops")
        }
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text(testIDValue)
                Text("\(testData.count)")
                EditTestItem(testData: testItem)
            }
            Button("Save", action: {
                try? modelContext.save()
            })
        }
        .modelContainer(for: TestData.self)
        .onAppear {

        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestContent(testID: "b")
        .modelContainer(for: TestData.self)
        .frame(width: 400)
}

The errors include:

Accessing Environment's value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.

and

Set a .modelContext in view's environment to use Query

It’s certainly not adding data.
What is the correct way of doing this?

IMHO, performing database access in a init(...) of a View is not a good idea.
I would move all this modelContext stuff to the .onAppear. Note, use Text(testData.id) in your EditTestItem

The Environment is never available on init. Use task

@loremipsum How would I do that?

@workingdogsupportUkraine Maybe I’m asking the wrong question. I’m using init() because I gather that’s the way to fake a dynamic @Query. If I move this code to onAppear{} I get an error because self is immutable. I’m trying to use @Query to search for an item, and, if not found, to create it.

posted my test code. I don't get any self is immutable errors.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks, I’m trying it now. However I’m getting an error which says default.store can’t be opened.

Note, I'm testing on real devices, not in Preview. On which line do you get the error?

updated my test code using TestData, works well for me.

I would create the test object in onAppear rather than using init.
For clarity lets have all related code in a single function that checks for an existing object and creates a new one if no one exists
private func load(with id: String) -> TestData? {
    do {
        var object = try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<TestData>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.id == id })).first

        if object == nil {
            object = TestData(id: id, value: "New value: \(id)")
            modelContext.insert(object!)
            try modelContext.save()
        }

        return object
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}

Then we need to do some changes to the view to hold the id and the object and call the new function
struct TestContent: View {
    let testID: String
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query var testData: [TestData]
    @State var testItem: TestData?

    init(testID: String) {
        self.testID = testID
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                // other components...
                if let testItem {
                    EditTestItem(testData: testItem)
                }
            }
            Button("Save", action: {
                try? modelContext.save()
            })
        }
        .onAppear {
            testItem = load(with: testID)
        }
    }

    private func load(with id: String) -> TestData? {
        // as above
    }
}


That’s quite a workable solution. I also note that you’re using FetchDescriptor rather than Query, which I presume helps to make it work.

Here is my test code that works for me, using TestData for testing.
struct ContentView: View {
    let testID: String = String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5))
    
    var body: some View {
        TestContent(testID: testID)
    }
}

struct TestContent: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query var testData: [TestData]
    
    var testIDValue: String = ""
    var testItem: TestData
        
    init(testID: String) {
        self.testItem = TestData(id: testID, value: "New value: \(testID)")
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text(testIDValue)
                Text("\(testData.count)")
                EditTestItem(testData: testItem)
            }
            Button("Save", action: {
                do {
                    try modelContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print("\(#line) oops")
                }
            })
            List {
                ForEach(testData){ test in
                    HStack {
                        Text(test.id)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(test.value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // .task {
        .onAppear {
            modelContext.insert(testItem)
            do {
                try modelContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("\(#line) oops")
            }
        }
    }
}
 
struct EditTestItem: View {
    @Bindable var testData: TestData
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(testData.id)
                TextField("Enter Data Here", text: $testData.value)
                    .border(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}


@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            TestData.self
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


Thanks for your help. I’ve complicated my application, so I’m still working on this but I think your answer does the trick. I’ll spend a little more time on my code and get back.
